# Cannot access XML Document using simplexml_load_file()

Tags: php, xml

I NEED HELP! I'm trying to generate XML document from my website database in hosting provider and accessing it from my home PC, right now I'm doing it in localhost environment. I use these codes and I got error message in browser. Please take a look at  my codes...

**data.php** for generating XML document

```
<?php
include ("koneksi-database.php");

header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo "<?xml version='1.0'?>";
echo "<outbox>";

$query = "SELECT * FROM `tbstatus` WHERE `status` = '$status' ORDER BY `ID`";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<data>";


    echo "<trx>".$data['trx']."</trx>";
    echo "<status>".$data['status']."</status>";
    echo "<signature>".$data['signature']."</signature>";
    echo "<time>".$data['time']."</time>";


echo "</data>";
}

echo "</outbox>";
?>
```

**read.php** for reading the XML document in localhost

```
print_r($dataxml = simplexml_load_file('data.php'));
```

I also create **index.php** for running the script every 5 seconds.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

var xmlhttp;

function ajax()
{

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp =new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            // do nothing
            }
        }


    xmlhttp.open("GET","read.php");
    xmlhttp.send();

    setTimeout("ajax()", 5000);
    }


</script>
</head>
<body onload="ajax();">
    <h1>Server is Running...</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

finally this the **error messages** that i get from browser when I open read.php.

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: data.php:9: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in C:\xampplite\htdocs\simpul\baca.php on line 9

Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: echo "<?xml version='1.0'?>"; in C:\xampplite\htdocs\simpul\baca.php on line 9

Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: ^ in C:\xampplite\htdocs\simpul\baca.php on line 9
```

Comment: The error literally tells you what the problem is.

Comment: @Shahar can you help me solve it?

Comment: try compiling just `header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo "<?xml version='1.0'?>";
echo "<outbox>";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `print_r($dataxml = simplexml_load_file('data.php'));` is reading you raw PHP file, not the script execution result!

`data.php` file have a PHP code that outputs a XML file, not a really XML file.

You should use `print_r($dataxml = simplexml_load_file('http://localhost/data.php'));` for example. (Assuming that `http://localhost/data.php` is the url to access your file.)

using only 'data.php' as parameter will get the raw file from server, not processed by PHP.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I try your code but now I get new error. `Warning: simplexml_load_file(http://localhost/data.php) [function.simplexml-load-file]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in C:\xampplite\htdocs\simpul\read.php on line 9` and `Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity "http://localhost/data.php" in C:\xampplite\htdocs\simpul\read.php on line 9` why you think this is?

Comment: The warning say everything.

URL `http://localhost/data.php` is not accessibile!

The url that I put in the code is just an EXAMPLE, you must change to your real situation.

Comment: Just replace it with the real URL to access `data.php` file.

Comment: Your answer solve my problem. Thank you very much. I change the URL to `$dataxml = simplexml_load_file('http://localhost/simpul/data.php')` and it works now.